# while文中の条件分岐について

Tags: c#, visual-studio

初歩的な質問ですみません。
現在while文を回しcount処理を行いフォルダーへの振り分けを行っています。
countの値が60の倍数になるとき、コンソール画面に文字を出力しようとしています。
countの値は1秒ごとに増えているはずなのですが、なぜEnterを押さなければ延々と
"Processing is finished.Please any key!"の文言が表示されるのでしょうか？
60の倍数の時、キー入力が無ければ文言を一度だけ出したいのです。

```
while(true)
{
if (NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValueStatus(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_ATTENTION) != 0)
                    {
                        string fileName = "";
                        Timer timer = new Timer(1000);

                        var count = 0;
                        int foldercount = 1;
                        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
                        {

                            String foldercountStr = foldercount.ToString();
                            if (count < 20)
                            {
                                fileName = fileNameFolder + foldercountStr + "data0to20.txt";
                                count++;

                            }
                            else if (count < 40)
                            {
                                fileName = fileNameFolder + foldercountStr + "data21to40";
                                count++;

                            }
                            else if (count < 60)
                            {
                                fileName = fileNameFolder + foldercountStr + "data41to60";
                                count++;

                            }else if (count % 60 == 0)
                            {
                                fileName = fileNameFolder + foldercountStr + "dataothers";
                                Console.Beep(10000, 500);
                                Console.WriteLine("Processing is finished.Please any key!");
                                ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey();
                                String strA = "Enter";
                                if (strA.Equals(input.Key.ToString()))
                                {
                                    count++;
                                }
                                
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                fileName = fileNameFolder + foldercountStr + "dataothers";
                                count = 0;
                                timer.Stop();
                            }
}
```

Comment: 提示されたソースコードは閉じ括弧`}`が2つ足らないし、`while`のループだけであって完結していないため、問題を再現・調査する環境を作るのが難しいでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容を改善してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ちなみにデバッグ実行で1ステップづつ実行させたり、ブレークポイントを設定して止まった時点での各変数の値を調べたり、そこからステップ実行させたりしてみましたか？

Comment: 説明が不十分で申し訳ないです。
コードを書き直して再度質問させていただきます。
デバックに関しては2,3回ループを回すと一秒に一度データを取得するところ、2秒に一回程になってしまうことを確認済みです。
変数の値は正常でした。

Comment: どういうことについて知りたいのかをはっきりさせるため、知りたい問題をより具体的にしたり、追加の詳細を書き加えたりしてください。現状のままだと何についての質問なのかが分かりづらいです。

Answer (score 0):

コードが不完全ですが、 `timer.Elapsed` の中身を省略すると

```
while (true) {
    if (NativeThinkgear.TG_GetValueStatus(connectionID, NativeThinkgear.DataType.TG_DATA_ATTENTION) != 0) {
        string fileName = "";
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000);

        var count = 0;
        int foldercount = 1;
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {};
    }
}
```

という構造になっているように見えます。もちろんこのループ自身には１秒待つという要素は存在せず、無限に回り続けます（毎秒`timer.Elapsed`が実行されますがそれはwhileループとは無関係です）。

ループが回るたびにタイマーオブジェクトが生成され、それぞれのタイマーが並列に１秒カウントを始めます。